# data not being inserted from servlet to mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am trying to make a registration page using java servlets, mysql database. here is part of my servlet code. There is no error output. database path is 100% correct

```
 String uName = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("passwd");
    String rpass = request.getParameter("rpasswd");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
        try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/userData";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "serv", "serv");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, em) values (?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stat.setString(1, uName);
            stat.setString(2, pass);
            stat.setString(3,email);
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: You forgot `stat.execute();`, also don't close the statement or connection in the try block close it in finally block

Comment: Or even better, use the try-with-resources statement to let it close it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
String uName = request.getParameter("username");
String pass = request.getParameter("passwd");
String rpass = request.getParameter("rpasswd");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/userData";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "serv", "serv")) {
    final String sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, em) values (?, ?, ?)";
    final PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stat.setString(1, uName);
    stat.setString(2, pass);
    stat.setString(3, email);
    stat.execute(); // you miss this
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

From the [PreparedStatement javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), `execute()` executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.